# Toggle and grey out a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I am trying to toggle a small StackPanel on top of a large StackPanel: when the small StackPanel is toggled and show visible, the large StackPanel on the back is grey out with a opacity color. Does anyone know how can I grey out a whole StackPanel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try to disable the `StackPanel` (`stackPanel.IsEnabled = false;`), then all children of that `StackPanel` will also be disabled which normally takes the apprearance of greyed out controls.

Comment: Thanks. I also would like to know how to grey out the stackPanel with a color. Like in CSS you can box a region with <div> and set a background color with opacity. I'm moving from web programming to desktop app. I can't figure out how to do that in C#...

Comment: That might actually warrant a question of its own. I don't know what kind of look you want to achieve exactly. but you can set the opacity of the StackPanel via `StackPanel.Opacity` and use a `SolidColorBrush` for the `StackPanel.Background` property to colour it. If you cannot get what you need that way you might need to place a rectangle for example beneath the `StackPanel` for the colouring.

Answer (score 3):

H.B.'s answer does not work on Windows Phone 8.1 A simple way to disable all children of a control is to wrap your controls inside a `<ContentControl x:Name="MyControl">` Then you can apply `MyControl.IsEnabled = false;` See [here](https://msarangam.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/how-to-isenable-property-for-stackpanel-in-silverlight/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stackPanel.IsEnabled = false;
```